# Maintaining Performance and Avoiding Timeout PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

Currently working on a project using Angular and PHP but the issue here is, i want to request to some large amount of data and perform some operations on the data before updating. What i did is to make a request to the PHP service to get the data in chunks of 200 at a time to my javascript (Angular). I then perform the operations on the data and make concurrent request to the PHP service and repeat all steps till all data are sorted out,  then i finally make a request to update all data operated on in another request to PHP service. Now, My question is this method good enough or are there other means to work around this?

```
/**here is the PHP service block code to make request**/
<?php
function listApplicantByApplicationComplete(){
$dao=new DaoOperations();
 $request=array('status'=>'APPLICATION_COMPLETE','programme_id'=>$_GET['programme_id'],'session_name'=>$_GET['session_name'],'session_id'=>$_GET['session_id']);
    //print_r($request);
    return $dao->listByLimit('user', $request,'&&',$_GET['page']);
}
?>



 /**
*here is my js file receiving the data and performing operations on the data
             * This is used to screen applicant in application complete
             * @param programme
             */
vm.startScreening = function(programme, newStart) {
    newStart = parseInt(newStart);
    if (newStart == 0) resetScreenSaver();
    console.log('newStart=' + newStart);
    console.log('currentApplicantPage=' + currentApplicantPage);
    vm.loader.hide = true;
    vm.loader.msg = 'Screening Applicants, this may take some minutes, please wait...';
    // if((!confirm('Are you sure you want to start screening process?'))) { return;}
    vm.thisProgramme = angular.copy(programme);
    var data = {
        programme_id: vm.thisProgramme.id,
        session_id: vm.session.id,
        session_name: vm.session.name,
        page: currentApplicantPage,
        request: 'listApplicantByApplicationComplete'
    };
    ApiHandler.callService('POST', '../datastore/services/applicationProcessServices.php', data)
        .then(function(resp) {
            console.log('applicant=', resp.data);
            if (resp.data != undefined && resp.data.status == 200) {
                vm.applicantsToScreen = [];
                vm.applicantsToScreen = resp.data.data;
                if (resp.data.data != undefined && resp.data.data != 0 && resp.data.data.length > 0) {
                    currentApplicantPage += 1;
                }
                newStart++;
                initializeScreening(); //calls the operations for data manipulation
            } else {
                newStart++;
                if (vm.screen.pass.length > 0 || vm.screen.fail.length > 0) {
                    saveScreenedApplicants();
                    return;
                }
                vm.loader.hide = false;
                Alert.error({
                    message: resp.data.message,
                    header: ''
                });
            }
        }, function(err) {
            vm.loader.hide = false;
            console.log(err);
            Alert.error({
                message: 'Error encountered Screening Applicants',
                header: ''
            });
        });
};
```